# How to create NER pipeline with multiple models in Spacy

Tags: python, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to train new entities for spacy NER. I tried adding my new entity to existing spacy 'en' model. However, this affected the prediction model for both `'en'` and my new entity.
I, therefore, created a blank model and trained the entity recognition. This works well. However, it is capable of predicting only the ones I have trained for and not the regular spacy entity recognition.

Say I trained 'horses' as ANIMAL entity.

For a given text

```
txt ='Did you know that George bought those horses for 10000 dollars?'
```

am expecting the following entities to be recognized

```
George - PERSON
horses - ANIMAL
10000 dollars - MONEY.
```

With my current setup, it only recognized horses.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
hsnlp = spacy.load('models/spacy/animal/')
nlp.add_pipe(hsnlp.pipeline[-1][-1], 'hsner')

nlp.pipe_names
```

this gives

```
----------------------
['tagger', 'parser', 'ner', 'hsner']
----------------------
```

However when I try to execute

```
doc = nlp(txt)  *<-- Gives me kernel error and stops working*
```

Please let me know how to create a pipeline for NER in spacy effectively. 
Am using **spacy 2.0.18**

Comment: This bug might help with this issue: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1752

Comment: Would love to see the right way to load and implement multiple `spaCy` NER models to one text after all the `spaCy`'s bug fixes.

Answer (score 9):

The main issue is how to load and combine pipeline components such that they are using the same `Vocab` (`nlp.vocab`), since a pipeline assumes that all components share the same vocab and otherwise you can get errors related to the `StringStore`.

You shouldn't try to combine pipeline components that were trained with different word vectors, but as long as the vectors are the same it's a question of how to load components from separate models with the same vocab.

There's no way to do this with `spacy.load()`, so I think the simplest option is to initialize a new pipeline component with the required vocab and reload the existing component into the new component by temporarily serializing it.

To have a short working demo with easily accessible models, I'll show how to add the German NER model from `de_core_news_sm` to the English model `en_core_web_sm` even though it's not something you'd typically want to do:

```py
import spacy # tested with v2.2.3
from spacy.pipeline import EntityRecognizer

text = "Jane lives in Boston. Jan lives in Bremen."

# load the English and German models
nlp_en = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  # NER tags PERSON, GPE, ...
nlp_de = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm') # NER tags PER, LOC, ...

# the Vocab objects are not the same
assert nlp_en.vocab != nlp_de.vocab

# but the vectors are identical (because neither model has vectors)
assert nlp_en.vocab.vectors.to_bytes() == nlp_de.vocab.vectors.to_bytes()

# original English output
doc1 = nlp_en(text)
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc1.ents])
# [('Jane', 'PERSON'), ('Boston', 'GPE'), ('Bremen', 'GPE')]

# original German output (the German model makes weird predictions for English text)
doc2 = nlp_de(text)
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc2.ents])
# [('Jane lives', 'PER'), ('Boston', 'LOC'), ('Jan lives', 'PER'), ('Bremen', 'LOC')]

# initialize a new NER component with the vocab from the English pipeline
ner_de = EntityRecognizer(nlp_en.vocab)

# reload the NER component from the German model by serializing
# without the vocab and deserializing using the new NER component
ner_de.from_bytes(nlp_de.get_pipe("ner").to_bytes(exclude=["vocab"]))

# add the German NER component to the end of the English pipeline
nlp_en.add_pipe(ner_de, name="ner_de")

# check that they have the same vocab
assert nlp_en.vocab == ner_de.vocab

# combined output (English NER runs first, German second)
doc3 = nlp_en(text)
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc3.ents])
# [('Jane', 'PERSON'), ('Boston', 'GPE'), ('Jan lives', 'PER'), ('Bremen', 'GPE')]
```

Spacy's NER components (`EntityRuler` and `EntityRecognizer`) are designed to preserve any existing entities, so the new component only adds `Jan lives` with the German NER tag `PER` and leaves all other entities as predicted by the English NER.

You can use options for `add_pipe()` to determine where the component is inserted in the pipeline. To add the German NER before the default English NER:

```py
nlp_en.add_pipe(ner_de, name="ner_de", before="ner")
# [('Jane lives', 'PER'), ('Boston', 'LOC'), ('Jan lives', 'PER'), ('Bremen', 'LOC')]
```

All the `add_pipe()` options are in the docs: https://spacy.io/api/language#add_pipe

You can save the extended pipeline to disk as a single model so you can load it in one line with `spacy.load()` the next time:

```py
nlp_en.to_disk("/path/to/model")
nlp_reloaded = spacy.load("/path/to/model")
print(nlp_reloaded.pipe_names) # ['tagger', 'parser', 'ner', 'ner_de']
```

Comment: This appears to be broken at least with me, locally, (spacy 2.1.8) where the behaviour seems to be "do not run NER" if `is_nered` is true.  In particular, I ran exactly this code with two different serialized NER models, and the third set of entities is exactly the same as the first set of entities.